# How to have these 2 kinds of citation?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I've read a paper in which there are 2 kinds of writing citations.
[image]

- `Freedman, 1963`
- `Diaconis (1988)`

In the first kind, the year is separated from the author by a comma. In the second kind, the year is put in a bracket. I'm able to do a second one. Could you please elaborate how to do like the first one?

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
@article{neymeyr2018set,
  title={On the set of solutions of the nonnegative matrix factorization problem},
  author={Neymeyr, Klaus and Sawall, Mathias},
  journal={SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications},
  volume={39},
  number={2},
  pages={1049--1069},
  year={2018},
  publisher={SIAM}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}

\begin{document}

A full in-text cite of \bibentry{goossens93}.

A regular citation of \cite{neymeyr2018set}.

A new citation of  \cite{goossens93}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mytestbib}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `\citep`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
@article{neymeyr2018set,
  title={On the set of solutions of the nonnegative matrix factorization problem},
  author={Neymeyr, Klaus and Sawall, Mathias},
  journal={SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications},
  volume={39},
  number={2},
  pages={1049--1069},
  year={2018},
  publisher={SIAM}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}

\begin{document}

A full in-text cite of \bibentry{goossens93}.

A regular citation of \cite{neymeyr2018set}.

A new citation of  \citep{goossens93}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

From the `natbib`-manual:

[image]